# Need to remove duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table that I have managed to get via a simple join between two temp tables. Now the expected result is a bit difficult to explain and I don't even know where to begin. So I will just post the expected result and answer any questions that may arise.

**Edit**: Basically need for each Date in both the columns to appear only once.

```
+----+------------------+----------------+----------------------+-----------     ---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| ID | Date from Source | Date to source | From Source Revision | To source Revision | From Source InstantID | To Source InstantID |
+----+------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 45 | 2015-06-19       | 2015-07-06     | P0                   | P0                 |                     1 |                   3 |
| 45 | 2015-06-19       | 2015-07-09     | P0                   | P0                     |                     1 |                   5 |
| 45 | 2015-07-27       | 2015-07-06     | P0                   | P0                 |                     6 |                   3 |
| 45 | 2015-07-27       | 2015-07-09     | P0                   | P0                 |                     6 |                   5 |
| 45 | 2015-07-28       | 2015-07-06     | P0                   | P0                 |                     7 |                   3 |
| 45 | 2015-07-28       | 2015-07-09     | P0                   | P0                 |                     7 |                   5 |
| 45 | 2015-07-30       | 2015-07-06     | P0                   | P0                 |                     8 |                   3 |
| 45 | 2015-07-30       | 2015-07-09     | P0                   | P0                  |                     8 |                   5 |
+----+------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+----+------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| ID | Date from Source | Date to source | From Source Revision | To source Revision | From Source InstantID | To Source InstantID |
+----+------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| 45 | 19-06-2015       | 06-07-2015     | P0                   | P0                 |                     1 |                   3 |
| 45 |                  | 09-07-2015     | P0                   | P0                 |                       |                   5 |
| 45 | 27-07-2015       |                | P0                   | P0                 |                     6 |                     |
| 45 | 28-07-2015       |                | P0                   | P0                 |                     7 |                     |
| 45 | 30-07-2015       |                | P0                   | P0                 |                     8 |                     |
+----+------------------+----------------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cce3)

Comment: Have you tried to use a Select Distinct statement?

Comment: I can see types rows for Date from Source as 19Jun and 27July are exactly the same , but even then why 19Jun has two rows and 27 July and rest are single rows??

Comment: Looking your output data, it seems to be you need to use cursor to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Id FROM (SELECT Id
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date from Source] ORDER BY [Date from Source]) AS [rn]             
        FROM myTable 
    ) a WHERE rn > 1 
)
```

Comment: You wouldn't really need to select all of the other data apart from the RN, would you? Also, `DELETE FROM CTE` would know how to reference the actual table? Isn't `CTE` just a result set? If the `CTE` would have multiple `JOINs`, how would the `DELETE` work then?

Comment: Hi @RaduGheorghiu would it matter if I mention that I only need the two Date columns in my result set ?

Comment: @Crabster:- Updated that!